# Why is Linking.getInitialURL always returning null?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm successfully using deep linking to open my app from a share extension. If the app is already running, then I get the information in `ComponentDidMount` using `Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);`

If the app isn't already running, I expect to be able to use `Linking.getInitialURL();` per the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking). Except it is always coming up `null` for me. The link is how my app is being opened, but no matter what, comes out as null. I have that code in componentDidMount in App.js.

I'm on react-native 59.2.

Here is my AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"MYMODULENAME"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

@end
```

If the app is already running in background, `getInitialURL()` returns the link that launched it, otherwise I get null. I expect to get the link that launched the app even if it wasn't running.

Answer (score 51):

The response was always `null` *if* I was debugging remotely. If the remote debugger was off, then I would get the correct url. I used an Alert to confirm since I couldn't console.log.

Comment: i have been struggling with this for hours! saved my day

Comment: glad to hear it! it drove me nuts for a whole day before the lightbulb finally went off

Comment: Great that you have updated this result. Been testing for quite some time, thanks Chia!

Comment: If app is inactive, you still got the URL from remote notification? I thought you have to handle deep URL inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: @chiaberry And if that's not the case...?

Answer (score 6):

Haven't been able to make `getInitialURL()` to work. However you can use:

```
Linking.addEventListener('url',(url)=>{ 
    console.log('this is the url: ',url);
});
```

This should give you the url, make sure to unregistered the event on `componentWillUnmount()`

Also I tried reverting to a react-native version that worked for me previously, however that still fails, so very weird that this issue is happening.

Comment: Anyone who's reading this: know that this will not get you the initial url from an intent opening the app (at least in Android). For that you need getInitialURL

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is looking for a quick fix just swap the result of `Linking.getInitialURL()` with the value of your app link manually, for example : `myapp://myhost`.

if you don't know what value you should put refet to this tutorial https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-handle-deep-linking-in-a-react-native-app/.